# Read header csv python from GCS bucket

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform

I want to extract header from a csv inside cloud storage GCP.
The problem is I extracted header, but I have a csv file with more than 20GB.

I used a library. It works to extract header, but it takes to much memory.

```
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT)
with fs.open(f'{bucket}/{file}', 'rb') as f:
    schema = f.read().decode("utf-8") 
    # Remove all words after the first new line
    schema = re.sub("(\\n).*", "", schema)
```

I tried this command too but it returns nothing:

```
fs.read_block('gs://my-bucket/my-file.txt', offset=1000, length=10, delimiter=b'\n')
```

My question is how to read only header not all file.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how to read only header not all file.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> schema = f.read()
> ```

This reads the whole file. Presumably, if `gcsfs.GCSFileSystem.open` works like the built-in file `open`, it should take an integer argument that specifies the number of bytes to read.

For example, if the header is 100 bytes in size, try:

```
schema = f.read(100)
```

Or, if the header is the first line in the file, separated by a `\n` character, try

```
schema = f.readline()
```